# SQL: Returning columns from table 2 when using left join on table 2 is null

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to return results from a left join where a list of values was not found in the second table, but I need my results to return specifically which of the values was not found.  I thought something like the following would work, but of course table2 is null, so I cannot pull a column out of it.

```
select table1.pidm, column1, column2, **column3** from
(select pidm, column1, column2 from aaa) table1
left join
(select pidm, column3 from bbb where **column3** in ('X','Y','Z')) table 2
on table1.pidm=table2.pidm where **table2.pidm is null**;
```

I've probably overlooked another simpler approach, but I cannot figure out what it is!

Comment: So you need to decide if there is no entry with the same `pidm` in `table2` or what is stored in `column3`?

Comment: Please provide your schema, sample data, and the expected result.

Comment: TheConstructor, there will be matching pidms in table 2, but I need the matching pidms that do not contain a X,Y or Z in column 3, and need to know specifically which of those was missing.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Your question, " but I need my results to return specifically which of the values was not found", does not make sense. By definition they were all missing.

Comment: @SparkyMcSparky was any of the answers usefull to you? You may want to accept one or provide further details.

Answer (score 1):

If the table structure of both the tables is exactly same, you can try this:

```html
select * from Table1

except

select * from Table2
```

If they are different, you can select the exact columns you require in the SELECT clause

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.pidm, x.CountX, y.CountY, z.CountZ 
from table1
left join
(select pidm, count(*) CountX from bbb where column3 = 'X' group by pidm) x on x.pidm = table1.pidm
 left join
(select pidm, count(*) CountY from bbb where column3 = 'Y' group by pidm) y on y.pidm = table1.pidm
left join
(select pidm, count(*) CountZ from bbb where column3 = 'Z' group by pidm) x on z.pidm = table1.pidm
```

This will give you all pidm's in table1, together with the count of related X, Y, and Z values.
If you want only pidm's where one of X, Y, or Z is missing, add this:

```
where x.CountX = 0 or y.CountY = 0 or z.CountZ = 0
```

(Edited to add ' group by pidm')

Answer (score 0):

Your query will select only entries from `aaa` where `bbb` does not contain any row by the same `pidm` (except rows where `column3` is not one of 'X', 'Y' or 'Z'). If you need to see which entries are missing, I see two general approaches. Let's have a look at them with this dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE `aaa` (`pidm` BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `column1` VARCHAR(10), `column2` VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO `aaa` (`pidm`, `column1`, `column2`)
VALUES (1, '1a', '1b'), (2, '2a', '2b'), (3, '3a', '3b'), (4, '4a', '4b'), (5, '5a', '5b'), (6, '6a', '6b'),
  (7, '7a', '7b'), (8, '8a', '8b');
CREATE TABLE `bbb` (`pidm` BIGINT, `column3` VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO `bbb` (`pidm`, `column3`)
VALUES (1, 'X'), (1, 'Y'), (1, 'Z'), (2, 'Y'), (2, 'Z'), (3, 'X'), (3, 'Z'), (4, 'Z'), (5, 'X'), (5, 'Y'), (6, 'Y'),
  (7, 'X');
```

## Join on a 'table' only containing 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' first

```
SELECT
  table1.pidm,
  table1.column1,
  table1.column2,
  temp1.column3
FROM
  aaa AS table1
  JOIN (SELECT
          'X' AS column3
        UNION SELECT
                'Y'
        UNION SELECT
                'Z') temp1
  LEFT JOIN
  bbb AS table2 ON table2.pidm = table1.pidm AND table2.column3 = temp1.column3
WHERE table2.pidm IS NULL;
```

This will result in 12 rows where each value of `column3` in the result will represent a `pidm` for which no row in `bbb` could be found. You can of course use this as a sub-query and create a similar result to approach 2.

## Count values directly

```
SELECT
  table1.pidm,
  table1.column1,
  table1.column2,
  COALESCE(SUM(table2.column3 = 'X'), 0) AS X,
  COALESCE(SUM(table2.column3 = 'Y'), 0) AS Y,
  COALESCE(SUM(table2.column3 = 'Z'), 0) AS Z
FROM
  aaa AS table1
  LEFT JOIN bbb AS table2
    ON table2.pidm = table1.pidm
GROUP BY table1.pidm;
```

This will result in 8 rows with the counts of each `column3` value for each `pidm` attached to the data of `aaa`.